# How to reference all <input> and <textarea> and do an action if they have :focus?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use plain Javascript to set up a function that fires when the S key is pressed AND the search overlay is not already open AND the S is not pressed when inside an `<input>` or `<textarea>`.  The issue is in the third argument and I can't seem to figure it out.

Can you please tell me how to set up the third argument in the IF statement?

I have been trying to get an equivent of the JQuery `is()` function in regular JS.  Since I don't know much about JS I am avoiding JQuery until I get the basics down. I have created a `class` for OOP, so the `this.` is referencing that.

My Javascript:

```
keyPressControl(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 83 && !this.isOverlayOpen && !document.querySelectorAll('input, textarea').hasFocus()) {

    this.staffSearchOpen();
    }
}
```

The `this.staffSearchOpen();` should function when all three arguments noted above are true, but I can only get the first two to work properly.

Comment: I'm assuming `hasFocus()` is not an array or node list method.  `querySelectorAll()` does not return a single DOM Element.

Comment: Taplar, I have seen hasFocus() .is() and other methods, but none seem to work for me. So this is just my most recent go at it.

Comment: `is()` is a jQuery method.  This question is asking for non-jQuery logic.

Comment: Taplar, I am aware of the `is()` method is in JQuery.  What's the equivalent in regular JS?

Comment: There's no *JavaScript* equivalent, but modern browsers support a `.matches()` method on Element nodes.

Comment: It's not a one-to-one comparison.  `is()` will accept any selector, including pseudo-selectors not implemented in vanilla javascript.

Comment: Pointy and Taplar, thank you for clarifying.  So how do I go about making the third argument in my logic?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/activeElement has fairly good browser support for getting the in focus element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wording of the question is a little confusing but it looks like you're trying to *exclude* event that happen when an input field is in focus, not the other way around.

Instead of "hasFocus()" you could just build the rule into the selector itself as `input:focus, textarea:focus`:

```js
document.addEventListener('keypress', function() {
  if (document.querySelector('input:focus, textarea:focus')) {
    console.log("keypress event was inside an input")
  } else {
    console.log("No input in focus");
  }
})
```

```html
<input>
<textarea></textarea>
```

...so your function could be:

```
keyPressControl(event) {
  if (
    event.keyCode == 83 && 
    !this.isOverlayOpen &&
    !document.querySelector('input:focus, textarea:focus')
  ) {
      this.staffSearchOpen();
    }
}
```

Comment: Daniel, did you update your answer?  The first version of it worked perfectly

Comment: I made a few early edits, did I break something along the way?

Comment: Daniel, no it's all good the second block of code is what I used and when I came back to the post it had the additional details above and I go confused, but we are all good.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Do it the other way around:

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('input, textarea');
elems.foreach(function (elem) {
  this.addEventListener("keydown",keyPressControl);
});

keyPressControl(event) {
  //you won't get a key event here unless the element is the focus owner
  if (event.keyCode == ...) {
    this.staffSearchOpen();
  }
}
```

Comment: Control, thank you for your suggestion.  I see what you did here, but I think this would only allow the desired function to run if the keypress is inside of an input.  I may be wrong though.  The desired effect is to allow the S keypress to open a search window, except when pressed inside of an input field